# cannot commit when i had created a file using git

Tags: git, commit, git-bash

[image: cannot commit getting the message in git bash]

I had configured globally both user name and Gmail before

```sh
git config  --global user.name “jayakrishnamurthy”
git config  --global user.email  jayakrishna.k14@gmail.com
```

tried this too after that to commit

```sh
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="@ jayakrishna.k14@gmail.comemail.com" && \
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=" jayakrishnamurthy " && git commit -m ”my first commit”
```

getting the error message after that

Comment: Check that the email is set correctly by checking the result with: `git config user.email`

Comment: One more thing, your `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` env variable is in the wrong format. Remove the leading `@ ` and make it just `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="jayakrishna.k14@gmail.com"`.

Comment: to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'jayak@LAPTOP-M7GJ9LAE.(none)')

Comment: ya tried but getting the same error

Comment: Did you try without the `--global` option?  Try exactly this (without even changing the email!): `git config user.email jay@example.com`  and then `git commit -m "test"`.

(Also please make your response easier for me to read by using complete sentences if possible.)

Comment: Also try this variant, please: `git config user.email "jay@example.com"`

Comment: now getting "nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)"

Comment: That means this part worked.

Try some "getting started with git" tutorial. However, to get one step further. Do this: Let's say you have a file "file.txt". Run `git add file.txt` and afterwards `git commit -m "first commit"`. But also use a GUI! VSCode comes with a good one by default.

Comment: trying in a min

Comment: I had created a file then executed the command git add file.txt and when I try to commit I am getting an error message that *nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)*

Comment: May I suggest asking a separate question for this, and marking my answer as accepted? I'd need more information to figure out why running `git add <...>` and then `git commit` does not work as expected. Also, I strongly suggest the use of a GUI and a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the E-Mail address in the correct format.

The format has to be just a plain E-mail format. While the exact E-mail address grammar is more detailed than I want to lay out here, a "normal" one will look like this: `jayakrishna.k14@gmail.com`.

- There shall not be any leading `@`, whitespace or other characters.
- Depending on the shell used, setting the email might require enclosing quotation marks. Thus you might have to set it using `git config user.email "jayakrishna.k14@gmail.com"`.
- Configuring the email globally would require that the git config is writeable. This should be the case by default but it is a potential issue. Just try it with `git config --global user.email "jayakrishna.k14@gmail.com"`